# @monthly cron job is not reliable

Tags: python, django, cron

Our customer wants us to create a report every month.

In the past, we used a @monthly cron job for this task.

But this is not reliable:

1. The server could be down in this minute. Cron does not re-run those jobs
2. If the server is up, the database could be unreachable in this moment.
3. If the server is up and DB is up, there could be a third party system which is not reachable
4. There could be a software bug.

What can I do, to be sure that the report gets created monthly?

It is a Django based web application

Comment: To do this you'd need some reliable way to keep track of the successful attempts to create the reports. Have you considered something like a `ReportCreationLog` model to log the successful attempts in your database? That way you could make sure all of your criteria would be met.

Comment: @Cole Yes you are right. I think I don't even need a log. I could check if the result is already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write some script that will test conditions and perform all required operations.

```
if is_work_finished_less_then_month_ago():
    return
else:
    try:
        generate_normal_report()
    except some_error as e:
        report_about_error(e)
```

Then run it every hour or day.

If you afraid of too many error_reports then do the same thing in `report_about_error()` method: check last time you sent report and do not send it if it's too often.

Comment: Is this related to Idempotence? I once read this in the celery docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-idempotent

Comment: @guettli Yes, it is «a function that can be called multiple times without changing the result. Practically it means that a function can be repeated many times without unintended effects, but not necessarily side-effect free in the pure sense».

Comment: Yes, I could use celery. But I like this simple solution. I could run this job every six hours. If it failed at midnight, it will re-run at 6 o'clock.

Answer (score 6):

**Use a decent scheduler**

> celery beat is a scheduler; It kicks off tasks at regular intervals, that are then executed by available worker nodes in the cluster.

You create a periodic task with the report function job. If the job fails celery will retry following the retry policy that you have set.

[Celery doc - Periodic Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: I worked once with celery. It felt big and complicated. A tool with less features might be better for my current use case. But nevertheless thank you for this answer. I up-voted.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I always used Celery and found it okay  so I can't help you anymore.

Comment: @guettli, It might feel big at first, though once the packages are setup and an optional [daemonization](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html) is in place, the actual code in the Django project is super short.

Answer (score 1):

Too many moving pieces and consequently options to consider. But problem 1 means you need some form of external way to track success (otherwise one option would have been for your server task - say a bash script - to keep retrying N times and sleeping in between retries, until the report generation is successful).

If you want a full-blown solution you can use for many different future needs, you can look into the available third party schedulers like Jenkins or SOS Berlin.

If you are looking for a simpler solution, you can schedule the report script via cron to run many times (say every hour for a few days at the end of the month), then have it keep track of whether the report was generated and sent successfully (this could be as simple as creating a file and checking for its existence, or writing a value to a database).

Comment: I fully agree with the "simpler solution". But if there's a software bug, multiple reports may be sent or created. There are only two solutions for that problem: 1) write correct software without bugs, or 2) don't write software.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is that you can write an helper such that the script checks for the availability of the report first and generates the report only if the report is unavailable.

Then schedule the script to run every hour on that day of the month.

change your script as follows:

```
if [[ -f <report_name> ]]
then
    echo "report exists" 
    exit 1
else
    echo "run generate report script"
```

crontab entry (To run every hour on 28th of every month):

```
0 0-23 28 * * <name_of_helper_script>
```

Answer (score 1):

cron is not able to do what you're asking for. And kicking off cron-like tasks via your Django app is not what Django was created for, and will only work if you handle all the edge cases and make sure to pick up missed runs if your app is malfunctioning, etc. It will be a rabbit-hole of error handling, state management and concurrency considerations.

I would suggest one of two options:

- Kick off the job with cron anyway, but write a Nagios check to ensure that you're notified if the report wasn't generated for some reason (and handle those rare cases manually).
- Use [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) or any other framework that was created specifically for the purpose of handling scheduling, monitoring, retrying and logging of scheduled tasks.

The former is what you want if this is really a one-off job. The latter is better if you have more tasks like this coming your way.

Comment: Apache Airflow looks very feature rich. I guess it has a valid use case. In my case it is far too big.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest going for cron as the simple solution, and then monitor that the report is actually generated. That's much easier than designing a system that cannot fail.

Comment: After thinking about the term "idempotence" ... I could call a script every hour. If the report exists, it does nothing. If it does not, the output gets created.